# Filtrar fullcalendar (resources y events) con un select - javascript jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando filtrar con un select los resource y eventos con la libreria fullcalendar, con el select quiero que carguen solo los resource con sus eventos pero mi problema es que cargan todos los resources no solo los que estan filtrados con el select. No se cual es el problema ya que por consola se puede ver los resource filtrados pero en la vista cargan todos los resource con sus eventos. Me pueden apoyar? Soy nuevo usando eso de fullcalendar quiza algo estoy que hago mal

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="especialidades">Especialidades</label>
    <select class="form-control m-input form-control-sm" id="especialidades">
    <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
    @foreach($especialidades as $d)
    <option value="{{$d->IdEspecialidades}}">{{$d->Descripcion}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="Calendario" class="mt-3 mb-3"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#especialidades').on('change', function(){
        $('#Calendario').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    });

    $('#Calendario').fullCalendar({
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        locale: 'es',
        resourceAreaWidth: 230,
        header: {
              left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'customWeek'
            },
        firstDay: 1,
        defaultView: 'customWeek',
        eventLimit: true,
        views: {
                customWeek: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    duration: { month: 1 },
                    slotDuration: {days: 1},
                    buttonText: 'Custom Week'
                },
            },
        resourceLabelText: 'Empleados',
        resources: '{{url('/VerEmpleados/CargarEmpleados')}}',
        events: '{{url('/VerEmpleados/Cargar')}}',
        //ESTO YO AGREGUE ULTIMO PERO NO PASA NADA
        resourceRender: function (resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
                console.log(resourceObj);
                return ['all', resourceObj.id].indexOf($('#especialidades').val()) >= 0
            }
    });
</script>
```

PD: Estoy que uso el defaultView: 'customWeek' y Agregue un comentario dentro del codigo donde hice que filtre pero igual muestran todos los resources y no los filtrados.